# I need assistance with a batch file that works perfectly on an older version of Windows 10 but not at all on a slightly newer one

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have this batch to compare the modified dates of two files that works great on an old version of Windows 10 '10.0.10240' but not at all on a slightly newer version of Windows 10 '10.0.17134.1304', so what am I missing here? Does the slightly newer version of Windows 10 require the installation of any additional software?

The batch file is as follows:

```
@echo off
Set _File1="D:\Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\game\dota\bin\win64\client.dll"
Set _File2="D:\Programs\client.dll"
For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('xcopy /DHYL %_File1% %_File2% ^|Findstr /I "File"') Do set /a _Newer=%%I 2>Nul
If %_Newer%==1 (Set _Newer=%_File1%) Else (Set _Newer=%_File2%)
Echo The newest file is %_Newer%
Pause
```

works perfectly on 'Windows 10.0.10240' but fails to start on 'Windows 10.0.17134.1304' (only opens for a fraction of a second and then immediately closes)

Comment: does running as administrator help?

Comment: If it closes, you almost certainly have a severe syntax error. Remove the `@echo off` and run it from an already open `cmd` window, NOT per double-click. The window will stay open, enabling you to read the code as it is being executed and any error messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, running it as administrator did not help, but entering the commands one by one in an open cmd seemed to work, so why doesn't it work in batch file?

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot I took https://imgur.com/wsN9ElR

Comment: in that case I would try what @Stephan recommends so you can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including the `/Q` option with `XCOPY`, there is no need to pipe through to `FINDSTR`.

You could therefore use this modification of your chosen `FOR /F` idea:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "_File1=D:\Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\game\dota\bin\win64\client.dll"
Set "_File2=D:\Programs\client.dll"
For %%G In ("%_File1%" "%_File2%") Do If Not Exist %%G (Echo A file is missing.& GoTo :EndIt) 
Set "_Newer="
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%_File1%" "%_File2%" /DHLQY 2^>NUL') Do If %%G Equ 1 (Set "_Newer=%_File1%") Else Set "_Newer=%_File2% or neither"
If Not Defined _Newer (Echo An error occurred.& GoTo :EndIt)
Echo %_Newer% is the newer file.

:EndIt
Pause
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

I have added some additional 'debugging' code to help you to determine what happens on each different system version, and to correct your assumption that `0` means that `%_File2%` is newer, when both may be datestamped the same.

Comment: Thank you so much @Compo!!, this worked perfectly for me on both Windows versions. Just one quick question: where does GoTo:EOF go?

Comment: The End Of File. It works similarly to `Exit /B`, it quits the script. You should not create or have a `:EOF` label, this is a special term, and the colon, _`:`_, is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that the response from `xcopy`, as filtered through `findstr` will either be `1 File(s)` or `0 File(s)` and this string is applied to `newer`

Your `if` statement then is resolved to

```
if 1 File(s)==1 ....
```

So you get a syntax error.

To resolve, remove the `"delims="` from the `for /f` which will then use the default delimiters which includes <kbd>Space</kbd> and return the default first token, which is `1` or `0`.

Only real puzzle is how it ever worked in your earlier Win10.

Obligatory sermon:

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements and home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any (error) messages will be displayed.

--- Revision ---

After a little experimentation, I looked a little closer at the code.

The `"delims="` delivers the strings I described - BUT - the `set /a` (rather than what I expected, `set`) would grab that number, then fail (hence the `2>nul`)

So - what I found is that if `file2` does not exist, the script stops waiting for a response to `xcopy`'s question "is file2 a file or directory?`

This may be the cause of the failure on clicking the batch.

So - I'd suggest

```
set "_newer="
if exist %_file1% set "newer=1"&if exist %_file2% for ...
if defined _newer (if _%_newer%==1....) else Echo %_file1% not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the "delims=" did not help me. the batch file still closes in a fraction of a second and does not perform the comparison. however, running the batch file from an open cmd or simply entering the code in it line by line works (no errors). I'm still confused as to why an open cmd works but batch does not.

Comment: I tried the code you recommended, but it still opens and closes without performing the comparison.

Comment: Worked for me, but compo's got it solved so we'll let it rest there.